# Does the onConnected callback's bundle parameter contain anything for Google Cast?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

The Google Cast Android SDK's callback for successfully connecting to a Cast device includes a Bundle passed as a parameter:

[void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected%28android.os.Bundle%29)

I haven't found any documentation about if this "connection hint" contains anything for Google Cast.  Is it possible to retrieve the RouteInfo object or Route ID of the connected Cast device, or anything else from this bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Cast, there is only one case that you can see a non-null value for the hint: if framework reconnects you after a transient loss of connectivity and if after reconnection the same app is not running on the Cast device anymore, then the connectionHint will have that information, namely, 
`connectionHint.getBoolean(Cast.EXTRA_APP_NO_LONGER_RUNNING)`
will return `true`.